# How to use SnackBar in Fragment when checking Internet connectivity?

Tags: android, fragment, internet-connection, snackbar

I have been building an online app and one of my main feature is to check whether it is connected to the Internet or not. I have decided to use a `Snackbar` to show this. But unfortunately, I have failed to do it. My app crashed upon running on my phone and it's pointing to a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I don't know if am I missing something here or there is wrong in my coding. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

**java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
01-12 17:09:35.273 32723-32723/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: org.cvsuimus.theflare, PID: 32723
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.cvsuimus.theflare/org.cvsuimus.theflare.MainPageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context org.cvsuimus.theflare.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context org.cvsuimus.theflare.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                       at org.cvsuimus.theflare.ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected(ConnectivityReceiver.java:33)
                                                       at org.cvsuimus.theflare.RecentNewsFragment.loadNews(RecentNewsFragment.java:70)
                                                       at org.cvsuimus.theflare.RecentNewsFragment.onCreateView(RecentNewsFragment.java:50)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1244)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6108)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
```

**RecentNewsFragment.java**

```
package org.cvsuimus.theflare;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.cvsuimus.theflare.ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected;

public class RecentNewsFragment extends Fragment {


    public RecentNewsFragment() {

    }

    final String TAG = "MainPageActivity";
    private RecyclerView rvNewsArticle;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_news, container, false);

        rvNewsArticle = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvNewsArticle);
        rvNewsArticle.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvNewsArticle.setLayoutManager(manager);
        loadNews();

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.primaryColor, R.color.primaryTextColor, R.color.secondaryColor);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadNews();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void loadNews() {
        if (isConnected()) {
            String url = "http://192.168.0.32/theflare/app/news.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response);

                            ArrayList<News> newsList = new JsonConverter<News>()
                                    .toArrayList(response, News.class);
                            final NewsArticleAdapter adapter = new NewsArticleAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
                            rvNewsArticle.setAdapter(adapter);

                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                snackInternet();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );

            MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
        else {
            snackInternet();
        }
    }

    private void snackInternet() {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(getView(), "No Internet Connectivity", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        loadNews();
                        Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(view, "Connected to the Internet!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar1.show();
                    }
                });

        snackbar.show();
    }

}
```

**isConnected method**

```
public static boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager
                cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

Comment: You might be having a null context on isConnected() method. Show your isConnected() method.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev I have included my `isConnected` method.

Comment: User the parent `View` for snackbar not the child `View`

Comment: Your getApplicationContext() might be returning null.